# How can I store the data of a windows phone when the user press Start button?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Something is wrong with my program, while is using the application and when exit and resume, the application crashes..

I'm using a List variable but, when the application resume, it has nothing in it.

I was using this.

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (State.ContainsKey("c"))
        {
            App.Contenedor.Add((List<int>)State["c"]);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        State["c"] =(List<int>)App.Contenedor[0];
    }
```

It seems working, but I'm not sure.. what do you think people?

Comment: Linked question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981140/how-to-save-application-state-variables-values-button-states-etc-in-windows

Answer (score 2):

You need to read up on [Tombstoning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff817008%28v=VS.92%29.aspx), the process where application sleeps while not active.

Check out the Activated and Deactivated events.

Answer (score 1):

You are saving/restoring data in the wrong methods. You shoud be *saving* data in `OnNavigatedFrom` and *restoring* data in `OnNavigatedTo`.

Comment: I don't get it, how would be that?

Answer (score 0):

The Tombstoning is rarely invoked in Mango anymore - your application sort of exists in limbo while you are using other apps on the phone.

All the events that have to do with saving and restoring state are in App.xaml.cs - respond to them if necessary.